# Mysterious FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, tomcat, servlets

I´m writing an Android app that communicates with a Tomcat Server running servlets. I´m doing a POST to the Tomcat server, specifying what file I want the server to send back to the client (the Android app). When I try to open this file by adding the file name sent with the POST to the catalog name I get a FileNotFoundException. But hardcoding exactly the same file name works just fine.

Copy pasting the file path obtained when the FileNotFoundException is thrown from the Tomcat servers console into windows explorer opens the correct file. I also wrote both the hardcoded file path, and the one where I append the file name to the catalog path, to a log file. In this log file both texts look exactly the same, and copy pasting both of them into windows explorer opens the correct file. Does anybody have an idea why this yields a FileNotFoundException?

Doing the post from client side

```
String potentialIP = "http://"+url+":8080/se.myPage/myServlet";
URL url = new URL(potentialIP);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

// Starts the query
conn.connect();

OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
byte[] byteArray = korning.getBytes();
out.write(byteArray);
out.flush();
```

And the doPost method on the server side looks like this

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(in).useDelimiter("\\A");

    String fileName = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    String filePath = "C:/myCatalog/"+fileName;

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:/myCatalog/Servletlog.txt", "UTF-8");
    writer.write("'"+"C:/myCatalog/hardCodedFileName.txt"+"'");
    writer.write("'"+filePath+"'");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));

    String svar = reader.readLine();
    reader.close();     
    out.close();
}
```

Anybody got an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I would suggest posting the log file. Also, I'm guessing you don't need the space in front of myCatalog in the filepath. That may be your problem -> C:/ myCatalog/hardCodedFileName.txt

Comment: Do you mean the Tomcat log file or the one that I made with PrintWriter? I don´t understand what space you are talking about? If you mean the "'" it is there for a reason - to make sure there are no newlines or empty spaces messing things up..

Comment: So you are saying that the server can't open the file for reading so it could return the content back to the client? What the `corning` variable contains in your client?

Comment: @wea I edited the space out. It should have only effected your logging though. It was an extra space in this line: writer.write("'"+"C:/myCatalog/hardCodedFileName.txt"+"'");, between the C:/ and the myCatalog/ parts of the path.

Comment: Better `korning.getBytes("UTF-8");` and `new BufferedReader(new ÌnputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), "UTF-8");` otherwise default platform encoding.

Comment: @Joop I applied your changes with no effect. I am however suspecting that I might be messing things up earlier on in my code..

Answer (score 0):

For me it turns out that the server was blocking whatever the default user agent is (maybe it was nothing) and was returning `403`. And this throws the `FileNotFoundException` on my try. I then changed to an example json from another server: http://date.jsontest.com/
This will return a json that looks like this:

```
{
   "time": "05:58:38 AM",
   "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1400047118645,
   "date": "05-14-2014"
}
```

By switching to another Server everything worked great - later I figured out that there is a problem with (as I said above) the user agent - set it to something like the Chrome user agent and it also should work normally.

Hope it will help you.